# Why does NGINX rewrite my url when I don't have a trailing slash? (url should not be rewritten)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a route such as `example.com/misc/page` to go to the same place as `example.com/misc/page/`. The route `/misc` goes to an s3 bucket that contains a bunch of other static pages that I am trying to serve. The config below works perfectly when I have that trailing slash but without the trailing slash the url gets rewritten to `example.com/page/`

```
location ~* ^/misc/?(.*)$ {
    ssi on;
    proxy_pass http://<%= ENV["PROXY_S3_BUCKET"] %>/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header Host <%= ENV["PROXY_S3_BUCKET"] %>;
    proxy_cache my_proxy;
    proxy_cache_key $host$request_uri$request_method;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this rewrite is happening and what I can do to prevent it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: bump. someone please help

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that amazon s3 was actually issuing a redirect back to my NGINX server due to the folder structure of the s3 bucket. In order to make sure the redirect coming back from amazon does not rewrite my url I had to make the folder structure of my s3 bucket match the structure of my url.